# How to get images from google?

Tags: android

I'm new at android stuff so be patience.
I'd like to implement a simple app with
a input text a button to get images
from google (for the version 2 from flicker as well :) )
and put them in a grid.
I'm following 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html
where I get the images statically but I've no idea 
implement it dynamically.
Can you give me a hint both to implement the research and set up the grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Declare String[] in main class like this

```
String[] mStrings={
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelib
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo_normal.png"};
```

then pass the String[] to adapter data

```
gridview=(GridView)findviewById(R.id.gridview);
 adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter like this

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("item "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the part of searching for a text in Google?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement Google Search Api.see below link for reference:

http://code.google.com/p/gsearch-java-client/

Comment: How do you use that API, and can you do this in Java?